# Combine 2 joins using OR between them in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, join, activerecord

I have two queries which gets me notes by joing different tables. You can find these queries below

```
User.joins(contacts: { practice: {contact_persons: :notes} }).where(id: 103).select("notes.*")

User.joins(contacts: {provider: :notes}).where(id: 103).select("notes.*")
```

I need results from both queries so I have to merge the results of both queries which I think is not a better approach. So I am trying to merge them using following query but it applies and on both join and I ended up only with result which fulfills both joins.

```
User.joins(contacts: [{ practice: {contact_persons: :notes} }, {provider: :notes}]).where(id: 103).select("notes.*")
```

Any solution to **combine above 2 queries to single one**?

Comment: The query is completely disfunctional to begin with. If you want notes start with that model and not users. You're going to get an ActiveRecord::Relation containing User instances but you're only selecting rows from notes. So this question is deep into X&Y problem territory. Provide an example of the data, model, and desired output instead of focusing on this code which is not going to get you anywhere.